# React on drag over view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view that I want to change whenever long press or drag occurs over it. It can start outside of the view, but also inside.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var active: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
        .fill(self.active ? Color.red : Color.secondary)
    }
}
```

An example of this behaviour is the iPhone keyboard: when you long press on a key it pops up (`active = true`). When you move outside it, it pops down (`active = false`) but the next key is then active.

I have tried using `LongPressGesture` but cannot figure out how to make it behave as I want.

Answer (score 0):

I made example for you in playgrounds to display how to use a `LongPressGestureRecognizer`.

You add the gesture recognizer to the view you want long pressed, with `target` being the parent controller handling the gesture recognition (`ContentView` in your case) and `action` being what happens with a long press.

In my implementation, a long press to the view `bodyView` changes its color from clear to red. This happens inside the `didSet` of the `showBody` property, which calls `showBodyToggled()`. I'm checking the `state` of the gesture, because the gesture recognizer will send messages for each state (I'm only performing the action if the state is `.began`).

Let me know if you have any questions:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    var bodyView: UIView!

    var showBody = false {
        didSet {
            showBodyToggled()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureSubviews()
        configureLongPressRecognizer()
    }

    func configureSubviews() {
        bodyView = UIView()
        bodyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bodyView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bodyView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            bodyView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            bodyView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            bodyView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
        ])
    }

    func configureLongPressRecognizer() {
        bodyView.addGestureRecognizer(
            UILongPressGestureRecognizer(
                target: self,
                action: #selector(longPressed(_:))
            )
        )
    }

    @objc func longPressed(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        // the way I'm doing it: only acts when the long press first happens.
        // delete this state check if you'd prefer the default long press implementation
        switch sender.state {
        case .began:
            showBody = !showBody
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func showBodyToggled() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.bodyView.backgroundColor = self.showBody ? .red : .clear
        }

    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

**EDIT:**

Here's an example in SwiftUI where a long press of 0.5 seconds toggles the color of a circle between red and black

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var active = false

    var longPress: some Gesture {
        LongPressGesture()
            .onEnded { _ in
                withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.4)) {
                    self.active = !self.active
                }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(self.active ? Color.red : Color.black)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .gesture(longPress)
    }
}
```

Comment: Real nice, but I am looking for a solution with SwiftUI.

Comment: @HugoLundin, edited my answer to include a SwiftUI example

Comment: That isn’t really the behavior I am looking for though. I want active to be true **whenever** a touch is on it, and stop whenever it is either released or dragged outside of the view.